# small php object oriented problem

Tags: php, oop, class, mysqli

i having problem understanding what is wrong with my inheritance. I just can not call most of the function of the parent. below is the function i am stuck.

```
class MySQLi_DB  extends mysqli {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private function __construct($db="test",$host="localhost", $user="root", $pass="") 
    {

        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
 static public function getDB()
    {
        if(self::$_instance == null)
        {
            self::$_instance = new MySQLi_DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;

    }


public function insert($table,$data)
        {
           $sql = $this->getQuery($table,$data);
           print $sql;
        }

        public function getQuery($table, $inserts) 
        {
            $lambda = function($value){
                return $this->real_escape_string($value);
            };

            $values = array_map($lambda,$inserts);
            $keys = array_keys($inserts);

            return 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')';
        }
```

I am having problem calling real_escape_string() function . i have tried using $this->real_escape_string() but i just have to see this error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
>   object context in
>   D:\wamp\www\Driver\MySQLi_DB.php on
>   line 49

ok may be that could be limitation of lambda function but i have tried it other way by declaring a callback for array_map that also doesn't allow me to call real_escape_string.

i am calling the function as below.

```
require_once 'MySQLi_DB.php';
        $db = MySQLi_DB::getDB();

        $insert_data = array("cmsId"=>444,"pageName"=>"New Insert");
        $db->insert("cms",$insert_data);
```

Please point out where i am doing wrong and what could be the best way to do it. thanks

Comment: where is the real_escape_string() function?

Comment: Can you post line 49 of MySQLi_DB.php if possible?

Comment: thats is the line in lambda function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the $this keyword into a lamba function as the scope of the function does not extend to the object whose method contains the lambda

Try a different approach:

```
 public function getQuery($table, $inserts) 
 {
      $values = array_map(array($this, 'real_escape_string'),$inserts);
      $keys = array_keys($inserts);

      return sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (`%s`) VALUES ("%s")',
           $table,
           implode('`,`', $keys),
           implode('","', $values)
      );
    }
```

**Addendum**

If *real_escape_string* is not a method of your object but the standard msqli method you should change the line

```
 $values = array_map(array($this, 'real_escape_string'),$inserts);
```

to

```
 $values = array_map(array(self::$_instance, 'real_escape_string'),$inserts);
```

to call the method real_escape string.

The array `array(self::$_instance, 'real_escape_string')` is a [callback array](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) and it is used when you want to call an object method.

The php manual states

*A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1*

and self::$_instance is the mysqli instance you want to call

Comment: can you please tell me how else i can use the real_escape_string of mysqli.

Comment: @g-molvi: Edited the answer to respond to  your comment

Comment: Thanks Eineki, that is the real solution

Answer (score 3):

```
$lambda = function($value){
    return $this->real_escape_string($value);
};
```

On your 'lambda' function the context is not your object, so $this is not available.

As an alternative, you could use, for example:

```
$values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $inserts)
```

or even try:

```
$values = array_map( array($this, 'real_escape_string'), $inserts)
```

this is untested but *should* work...

Comment: you rock maan. it is working amazing...can you please teach me what does this line of your means (array ( $this, 'real_escape_string') ?

Comment: A callback (what is passed to array_map) can be either: a function, a function name, an array of (object, function), or array of (static class name, static function name)